# Using dotenv in a Node JS module

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, node-modules

I am building a Node app that returns results for a search using a Google Custom Search Engine(CSE).

I am going to separate the part of the app that sends the request to Google and returns the results into a module.

I use [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) already in the app to store MongoDB credentials and the app's URL.

I also want to use dotenv in the module to store the Google CSE ID and the API key for the CSE.

I want my module to work independently of the main app but also to use the main app's dotenv file when it's a module.

Currently my module structure looks like this:

```
module
 |
 +-- node_modules
 |  |
 |  \-- dotenv
 |     |
 |     \-- (dotenv module's files....)
 |
 +-- .env
 |
 \-- index.js
```

This works perfectly on its own. The .env file stores the required environment variables and I can access them in the index.js file by requiring the dotenv module.

When included in the main app the structure looks like this:

```
app
 |
 +-- node_modules
 |  |
 |  +-- dotenv
 |  |  |
 |  |  \-- (dotenv module's files....)
 |  |
 |  \-- my_google_search_module
 |     |
 |     +-- node_modules
 |     |  |
 |     |  +-- dotenv
 |     |     |
 |     |     \-- (dotenv module's files...)
 |     |
 |     \-- index.js
 |
 +-- .env
 |
 \-- index.js
```

This also works. I store all the environment variables in the main app's .env file and by requiring dotenv in the app's index.js I can access those variables. Plus, the "my_google_search_module" seems to be pulling its required variables from the .env file in the root of the app. There is no .env file in the module.

My question is am I doing this the right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have researched this further and can confirm that the module's `.env` is pulling the required environment variables from the app's `.env` file.

I believe this section from the dotenv readme, though not exactly related, verifies that -
https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv#what-happens-to-environment-variables-that-were-already-set

> We will never modify any environment variables that have already been
>   set. In particular, if there is a variable in your .env file which
>   collides with one that already exists in your environment, then that
>   variable will be skipped. This behavior allows you to override all
>   .env configurations with a machine-specific environment, although it
>   is not recommended.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are doing in a right way. There must be a single .env file in a whole project. But there is a trick to include it in the different directory structure.
For example:
Your index.js file is in /app/src, your .env file is in /app. Your index.js file has this

dotenv.config({path: "../.env"});

You could also use dotenv.config({path: path.join(__dirname, "../.env")});

Answer (score -1):

for node projects, i would suggest to use npm package [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv). You can find details on how to use it. do not forget to include `require('dotenv').config()` at the start of your project file, say index.js.

Now you can use `.env` contents anywhere you need. For example i want my server port to be 4000 which i define in `.env` as `PORT=4000`. Now, to use `.env` variables anywhere, simply provide variable name in suffix such as `process.env.PORT`. That is it. Though i am late on this post, hope this could be of any help.